# Split txt file into multiple files on each line break

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, vba

I'm looking to split a txt file into multiple files each time there is a line break / no text on the row.

Is this possible using PowerShell?

Does anyone have a script for this?

This is an example of the data:

[image: Notepad screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell script does exactly what you required.
Each section is saved with the same file name and an appended incrementing number.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\27\SU_1334727.ps1
$FileName = '.\test.txt'
If (Test-Path $FileName){
    $File = Get-Item $FileName
    (Get-Content $File.FullName -Raw) -Split "(?<=`r?`n *`r?`n)" |
        ForEach-Object {$i=1}{
            $_ | Set-Content ("{0}_{1}{2}" -f $File.BaseName,$i++,$File.Extension)
        }
}
```

- the file is read in as a continous piece of text and split by a nonconsuming Regular Expression using a positive look behind

Sample output:

```
> gc .\test_1.txt
1        sf
1        s
1        sg
1        sv
1        sgsv
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do the and a quick search on web using …

> Powershell 'split a file on line feed'

… would return several hits.

It could be as simple as using the New-Item, Get-Children and Add-Content cmdlets using a loop and a condition.

```
$Lines = Get-Content 'D:\Scripts\$data.txt'

New-Item -Path 'D:\Scripts' -Name 'FileName.txt' -ItemType File
$FileName = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Scripts\FileName.txt').FullName

$FileCount = 0

ForEach($Line in $Lines)
{
    If($Line -ne '')
    {
        'Appending line to a file'
        Add-Content -Value $Line -Path $FileName
    }
    Else
    {
        'Empty line encountered - creating new file'
        $FileName = New-Item -Path 'D:\Scripts' `
        -Name (((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Scripts\FileName.txt').BaseName + 
        ($FileCount = $FileCount + 1) + '.txt')) -ItemType File
    }
}
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Scripts\filename*'

# Results

    Directory: D:\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                  
-a----        27-Jun-18     12:48              0 FileName.txt                                                                                                                                                          
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
Empty line encountered - creating new file
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
Empty line encountered - creating new file
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
Appending line to a file
-a----        27-Jun-18     12:48             21 FileName.txt                                                                                                                                                          
-a----        27-Jun-18     12:48             21 FileName1.txt                                                                                                                                                         
-a----        27-Jun-18     12:48             21 FileName2.txt
```